# Is it possible to automatically convert java code to PHP?

Tags: java, php, converters

Is there are tools for converting java code to php? I have source code of java library and I need it to convert to php.

Comment: why do you want to? just, for personal interest

Comment: I have write good date time parser in java, and some guys want it in php

Comment: There is a Kotlin to a simple PHP: https://github.com/jtransc/jtransc/issues/85, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KmxPamdRI9A . And there is a Java to Kotlin converter working great in IntelliJ IDEA.

Answer (score 11):

It is possible to automatically convert it. This is called a source to source compiler. Normally when you compile software, the parser will build an abstract syntax tree and convert this into the target machine language code. But it is just as possible to have a compiler convert this into another high level (compilable) language.

Java is a strongly typed language, and PHP is not, so source to source compilers are rare and the code conversion process is incomplete. However this said, there is a reasonably good one with a free demo at: http://javatophp.com

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Ok thanks for the tip. I'm new to stack overflow. I added some more info to go along with the link.

Comment: It doesn't work for me :( I pack the java file to zip, upload, then "new.php" appears in the browsers, all good. But when I click the php file, it shows "file not found".

Comment: this is the answer, when `While this link may answer...` and such comments should be just neglected  :)

Comment: No, it's not. Right now "answer" shows "This site can’t be reached". Thats why Radim was right

Answer (score 5):

Automatically - No. Now. Maybe in future. Don't spend time, write new code bro.

Comment: This answer is now outdated: see [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17333782/975097).

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a solution like this currently.

You might try using a php-java bridge that would allow you to call the java code from within PHP:
http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/

[Zend Server](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) also provides a bridge

Answer (score 2):

Team of 5 folks at [Facebook](http://facebook.com/) have spent 18 month to write sofrware that converts [PHP](http://php.net/) to C++ (meet: [HipHop](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/wiki/)). There is no such software for transforming from Java to PHP yet.

The answer is: yes... it is possible if you have year and a half and team of pro programmers :)
Otherwise, you rewrite it manually (I think, this is your choise).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of aspects of Java that cannot be expressed in PHP. Type safety for one. This sounds like a fool's errand to me. If you were looking to go in the opposite direction the question might have some interest.

Comment: I don't need to safe strong type aspect, I need only code thats works same way as java code.

Comment: @yura You're assuming that's the only aspect I referred to. It isn't. Why do you think you need to do this?

Comment: I have written date time parser in java, and some guys want it in php

Comment: @yura So rewrite it in PHP. You don't need a tool to convert a few dozen lines of code.

Comment: I don't approve the downvote since this answer addresses right issues! In fact, in my perspective the question is similar to the following: **can I transform a donkey in a Ferrari?** Hence, I'll upvote this answer!

Comment: Downvoting because you are suggesting an anti-PHP rant and above all, I totally disagree with your view : it is much easier to go from a well-structured, strongly-type code, i.e. from Java to PHP, than the other way around. So I don't see any reason why "the opposite direction" would have more interest : it's simply much more difficult; The interest only comes from the fact some company or people wants code in a language

Comment: @spiritoo You have misread this completely. If you want an anti-PHP rant I can certainly give you a good one, but I haven't done so above. I have stated a *fact* about type safety, and the same fact appears in other answers here. I didn't say anything about 'easier'. I am talking about desirability.